# Multiple relationships in Match Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Trying to find similar movies on the basis of tags. But I also need all the tags for the given movie and its each similar movie (to do some calculations). But surprisingly `collect(h.w)` gives repeated values of h.w (where `w` is a property of `h`)

Here is the cypher query. Please help.

```
MATCH (m:Movie{id:1})-[h1:Has]->(t:Tag)<-[h2:Has]-(sm:Movie),
(m)-[h:Has]->(t0:Tag), 
(sm)-[H:Has]->(t1:Tag) 
WHERE m <> sm 
RETURN distinct(sm), collect(h.w)
```

Basically a query like

```
MATCH (x)-[h]->(y), (a)-[H]->(b) 
RETURN h
```

is  returning each result for `h` `n times` where `n` is the number of `results for H`. Any way around this?

Comment: Are `b` and `sb` supposed to be `m` and `sm`? Could you say again what you want returned? It looks like you return the related movie `sm`, but then you collect tags from `m` and group them by `sm`... that may be your problem. Do you have a console sample?

Comment: Ahh yes, that was a typing error, I am sorry for that. Have corrected the code. 

I want all possible relationships connected to the movie `m` & `sm` ,and also only the relationships on the tag which are common to `m` and `sm`.

Comment: That is I want h, H, h1, h2. But somehow there value is getting repeated which is affecting the calculations related to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replicated the data model for this question to help answer it.

[image: Example data model]

I then setup a sample dataset using Neo4j's online console: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=dakmi3

Running the following query from your question:

```
MATCH (m:Movie { title: "The Matrix" })-[h1:HAS_TAG]->(t:Tag),
      (t)<-[h2:HAS_TAG]-(sm:Movie),
      (m)-[h:HAS_TAG]->(t0:Tag),
      (sm)-[H:HAS_TAG]->(t1:Tag)
WHERE m <> sm
RETURN DISTINCT sm, collect(h.weight)
```

Which results in:

(1:Movie {title:"The Matrix: Reloaded"})    [0.31, 0.12, 0.31, 0.12, 0.31, 0.01, 0.31, 0.01]

The issue is that there are duplicate relationships being returned, which results in duplicated weight in the collection. The solution is to use WITH to limit relationships to distinct records and then return the collection of weights of those relationships.

```
MATCH (m:Movie { title: "The Matrix" })-[h1:HAS_TAG]->(t:Tag),
      (t)<-[h2:HAS_TAG]-(sm:Movie),
      (m)-[h:HAS_TAG]->(t0:Tag),
      (sm)-[H:HAS_TAG]->(t1:Tag)
WHERE m <> sm
WITH DISTINCT sm, h
RETURN sm, collect(h.weight)
```

(1:Movie {title:"The Matrix: Reloaded"})    [0.31, 0.12, 0.01]

Comment: Thanks but finding recommendations is not the issue for me. The problem is in the calculation related to it.

a query like

**MATCH (x)-[h]->(y), (a)-[H]->(b) 
RETURN h
is returning each result for h n times where n is the number of results for H. Any way around this?**

Comment: You need to explain more about your data model. What is h.w?

Comment: h is the relationship between the movie and any of its tags..`(m)-[h:Has]->(t0:Tag)`, while in **h.w (w is a property of h)**

Comment: I guess what's been explained above is sufficient. What more you think is required?

Comment: I understand that w is a property of h, but what is it?

Comment: Its the weight for that relationship.

Comment: Have you tried using different identifier names for H and h? For instance h1 and h2?

Comment: If you're on Skype, reach out to me kenny.bastani and I can help more rather than back and forth here

Comment: yes I just did, the same issue still persists. And I don't think naming the variables differently will differ how the cypher queries work. The issue is with using two relationships simultaneously in MATCH, which makes results to be repeatedly shown.

Comment: have put the skype on download. Thanks, will be there in 10-15mins.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I still don't quite get your intention, but about the general question of duplicate results, that is just the way a disconnected pattern works. Cypher must consider something like

```
(:A), (:B)
```

as *one* pattern, not *two*. That means that any satisfying graph structure is considered a distinct match. Suppose you have the graph resulting from

```
CREATE (:A), (:B), (:B)
```

and query it for the pattern above, you get two results, namely

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (a:A),(b:B) RETURN *;
==> +-------------------------------+
==> | a             | b             |
==> +-------------------------------+
==> | Node[15204]{} | Node[15207]{} |
==> | Node[15204]{} | Node[15208]{} |
==> +-------------------------------+
==> 2 rows
==> 53 ms
```

Similarly when matching your pattern `(x)-[h]->(y), (a)-[H]->(b)` cypher considers each combination of the two pattern parts to make up a unique match for the one whole pattern–so the results for `h` are compounded by the results for `H`.

This the way the pattern matching works. To achieve what you want you could first consider if you really need to query for a disconnected pattern. If you do, or if a connected pattern also generates redundant matches, then aggregate one or more of the pattern parts. A simple case might be

```
CREATE (a:A), (b1:B), (b2:B)
    , (c1:C), (c2:C), (c3:C)
    , a-[:X]->b1, a-[:X]->b2
    , a-[:Y]->c1, a-[:Y]->c2, a-[:Y]->c3
```

queried with

```
MATCH (b:B)<-[:X]-(a:A)-[:Y]->(c:C)              // with 1 (a), 2 (b) and 3 (c) you get 6 matched paths
RETURN a, collect (b) as bb, collect (c) as cc   // after aggregation by (a) there is one path
```

Sometimes it makes sense to do the aggregation as an intermediate step

```
MATCH (b)<-[:X]-(a:A)              // 2 paths
WITH a, collect(b) as bb           // 1 path
MATCH a-[:Y]->(c)                  // 3 paths
RETURN a, bb, collect(c) as cc     // 1 path
```